# How to capture all motion events using a listener/listeners

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to capture all motion events from the screen using a listener for example if i do a swipe on a screen from top to bottom there will be a touch down, touch move and a touch up. Since this touch will be over multiple views example linear view, buttons and text fields i tried to attach on touch listeners to all views but i would get bad data for example i would get touch up without touch downs and so on. Please advise a way that will achieve this.

Comment: When a touch start on a view. Android keeps sending to the same view until you remove your finger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to attach the **OnTouchListener** to the parent ViewGroup (layout) of all your views.

For example a RelativeLayout that have multiple views (linear view, buttons and text fields) as you mention in your question. You can do like that:

```
RelativeLayout currentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.MyRelativeLayout );
currentView.addView(aSubView);
currentView.addView(aSubButton);
currentView.addView(aSubTextView);

currentView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Here you will receive all the motion event.
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i just tried this it doesnt work! ... since the other views are already children you can add them again. Plus attaching the listener to the root only with the kids attached wont capture all motion events

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method in you activity.

It's called before the MotionEvent is forwarded to the different Activity Views.

You can then do what you want with it, forward them, consume them...

Comment: i would like to do it using listeners